# jquery mobiscroll and jquery validate won't play nice together

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-validate, conflict, mobiscroll

i'm working on a jquery mobile web site.  and am trying to use the [mobiscroll](http://demo.mobiscroll.com/)  plugin for the date picker.

I'm using [jquery validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) plugin for my validation.  I've used this all over other projects with no problems at all.

The issue is,  the mobiscroll modal popup comes up,  and the set / cancel button works fine,  but the scrolling and/or +/- buttons do not function.

firebug isn't showing any errors, and IE Developer tools script debugger doesn't either.

If i take the jquery Validate reference out, it works fine.  removing the `$('form').validate();` does NOT fix it.

for reference i'm using:

- jquery 1.7.1
- jquery mobile 1.1.0
- jquery validate 1.6
- mobiscroll 1.6 or 2rc2 (both have the issue)

How i have mobiscroll configured doesn't seem to matter, leaving all the options out, or setting some doesn't seem to make a difference.

Having other inputs with or without validation on them doesn't make a difference either.

Here is my setup code:

```
$('#DateVolunteered').scroller(
   {
      preset: 'date',
      theme: 'default',
      display: 'modal',
      mode: 'scroller'
    }
);
```

and the input:

I tried making a jsFiddle, but am having some issues with getting the various libraries referenced and all the css and whatnot. I will keep working on it and post a link when i get it up and running.

EDIT:
I can't get a fiddle to work. BUT I have discovered that updating to 1.9 fixes it.  very strange. but i'll take it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updating to jquery validate 1.9 fixed it.